# Can a Swashbuckler use Confident Finisher in Crane Stance?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, swashbuckler

In [Crane Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=430) you can only use Crane Wing:

> but the only Strikes you can make are **crane wing** attacks. These deal 1d6 bludgeoning damage; are in the brawling group; and have the **agile, finesse**, nonlethal, and unarmed traits.

[Confident Finisher](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=550):

> You make an incredibly graceful attack, piercing your foe's defenses. Make a Strike with a weapon or **unarmed attack that would apply your precise strike damage**, with the following failure effect.

Crane Wing has both Agile and Finesse, so it qualifies.
**The question is, are Crane Wings attacks basically a type of Strike (which prevents Finishers) or a type of weapon (which would allow it)?**

(you can get Crane Stance on a Swashbuckler with a Dedication + a feat)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Crane wing attacks are agile unarmed Strikes and work with Confident Finisher

It says so right in the quote you give:

> the only **Strikes** you can make are crane wing **attacks**

This makes it clear that the crane wing attack is a usually a Strike (and of course an attack).

[Strikes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=89) are not weapons. They are attacks (have the Attack trait). They *can* be weapon attacks when you attack with a weapon, but they also can be unarmed attacks if your are not using one. Their text says:

> You attack with a weapon you're wielding or **with an unarmed attack**.

Here, you are *holding your arms in an imitation of a crane’s wings and using flowing, defensive motions*, so you make unarmed attacks with your arms. [Unarmed attacks](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=199) do not count as weapons:

> An unarmed attack uses your body rather than a manufactured weapon. **An unarmed attack isn't a weapon**, though it's categorized with weapons for weapon groups, and it might have weapon traits

However, none of this stops you from using Confident Finisher with your strike. It allows you to use an unarmed attack (see your quote), and the [**precise strike** feature](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=15) likewise works with unarmed attacks:

> you Strike with an agile or finesse melee weapon **or agile or finesse unarmed attack**

and the Crane Wing attack is an agile unarmed attack. I see nothing in the rules on precise strike, finishers or on panache that would require you to attack with a weapon.

Comment: @Ruse I think you are right, if the only strikes you can make are crane wings, it is not conculsively following that crane wings can be only strikes.